# multiple if statements check optimize

Tags: javascript

My code has mutiple checks for if staments which I think could be optimized into few lines if I take id into varibable. To give some background I want to disable a button based on length of characters in input box. But the thing is out of two buttons only one will be rendered at a time. 
Below is my working version of code which I am hoping to optimize.

```
  var sortcodeError = document.getElementById("sortcodeError")
         var accountnameError = document.getElementById("accountnameError")
          if (sortcodeError != null) {
                  document.getElementById("sortcodeError").disabled = false;
               }
               if (accountnameError != null) {
                  document.getElementById("accountnameError").disabled = false;
               }
         if ($scope.data.branchTransitNumber && $scope.data.depositAccountNumber) {
            if ($scope.data.branchTransitNumber.length < 6) {
               if (sortcodeError != null) {
                  document.getElementById("sortcodeError").disabled = true;
               }
               if (accountnameError != null) {
                  document.getElementById("accountnameError").disabled = true;
               }

            }
            if ($scope.data.depositAccountNumber.length < 8) {
               if (sortcodeError != null) {
                  document.getElementById("sortcodeError").disabled = true;
               }
               if (accountnameError != null) {
                  document.getElementById("accountnameError").disabled = true;
                  // angular.element($('#btnSubmi')).addClass("gray");
               }

            }
         }
```

My initial thought is if I could take `id` as varibale but then I don't think it is the best way

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: @Mast yes I will and change the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since exactly one element will exist at a time, you can retrieve it by alternating with `||` between both `getElementById` calls. Then, there's no need for any existence test later.

Since you set disabled to true in both `branchTransitNumber.length < 6` and `depositAccountNumber.length < 8`, you can combine those blocks together:

```
const button = document.getElementById('sortcodeError') || document.getElementById('accountnameError');
button.disabled = false;
if ($scope.data.branchTransitNumber && $scope.data.depositAccountNumber) {
    if ($scope.data.branchTransitNumber.length < 6 || $scope.data.depositAccountNumber.length < 8) {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

(The above can be made even more concise via destructuring or optional chaining to avoid the double `if`s, but I think it'd look too confusing.)

Or, if you need the `addClass` call *only* in the case of `$scope.data.depositAccountNumber.length < 8` **and** `accountnameError` existing:

```
const button = document.getElementById('sortcodeError') || document.getElementById('accountnameError');
button.disabled = false;
if ($scope.data.branchTransitNumber && $scope.data.depositAccountNumber) {
    const depositNumberProblem = $scope.data.depositAccountNumber.length < 8;
    if ($scope.data.branchTransitNumber.length < 6 || depositNumberProblem) {
        button.disabled = true;
        if (depositNumberProblem && button.id === 'accountnameError') {
            angular.element($('#btnSubmi')).addClass("gray");
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the logic of your script, the above may be simplifiable. For example, you may wish to do `.addClass("gray")` regardless when you disable the button.

Other notes:

- It's 2020, best to *at least* use ES2015 syntax in new code by declaring variables with `const`, not `var` (which has too many gotchas)
- Whenever you do have to compare two different values, use strict equality with `===` or `!==` - avoid loose equality `==` and `!=`, since loose equality has [too many strange rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) that a developer should not have to memorize.
- If the alternation trick above weren't possible, you'd still be able to reference the variable names you saved the elements into to keep things concise. Eg, with `const sortcodeError = document.getElementById("sortcodeError")`, you should never have to call `document.getElementById("sortcodeError")` later - instead, just reference the `sortcodeError` variable.
- Use consistent indentation. If one statement is in the same block as another, it should begin at the same indentation level. This significantly improves a code's readability.
- Either use semicolons wherever appropriate, or don't. (If you're not an expert, I'd recommend using them, otherwise you'll occasionally run into strange bugs.) Consider using [a linter](http://eslint.org/) to automatically prompt you to fix potential mistakes (and to make the code nicer-looking).
- The overall logic looks a bit weird. Do you *really* need to check that both `branchTransitNumber` and `depositAccountNumber` exist, but disable a button if *either* of them fail a length test? In a validation situation, I'd expect to disable a button if either fail, rather than if *both exist **and** either fail*. Double-check the logical paths your code requires and results in, and consider what sort of effect you *really* want.

Comment: About last point. I am really new to this and when I didn't check if they exist or not. It gave me length of null error

Comment: If it's just to avoid the error, then check *separately*, not together. Eg `if ((branchTransitNumber && branchTransitNumber.length < 6) || (depositAccountNumber && depositAccountNumber.length < 8))`